# Can't retrieve LatLng from inner class

Tags: java, android, class

I'm sending an `IntentService` call from `MainActivity` to a class called `MapClass`. The `MapClass` has an inner class called `MapClassInner`, which computes the current coordinates of the user. However, the outer class contains the `onHandleIntent` method, which will ultimately send the coordinates back to `MainActivity` using a Broadcast. My question is - How can I access the inner variables of `MapClassInner`? I'm pretty sure the answer is simple, but I've been on this project for 2 hours straight, so my thinking's become a bit awry.

Here's the code (MapClass.java):

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import meetup.be2015.gcm_meetup.MainActivity.MyLocationReceiver;


public class MapClass extends IntentService {
    public static final String REQUEST_STRING = "myRequest";
    public static final String RESPONSE_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String RESPONSE_LNG = "lng";
    public GoogleMap map;

public MapClass() {
    super("MapClass");
}

private class MapClassInner extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private GoogleMap mgoogleMap;
    private LatLng latLng;

    private GoogleApiClient client;

    public MapClassInner(GoogleMap map){
        this.mgoogleMap = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("ON_MAP_READY","In OnMapReady");
        mgoogleMap = googleMap;
        mgoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);      //Sets location to current position
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } 

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.d("BUILD", "In buildClient()");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("ON_CONNECTED","In onConnected()");
        Location MLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (MLastLocation != null) {
            latLng = new LatLng(MLastLocation.getLatitude(), MLastLocation.getLongitude());


        } else {
            Log.d("onConnected", "Value of LatLng is NULL");
            latLng = new LatLng(0, 0);   
        }
    }

    public LatLng getLatLng(){
        return this.latLng;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Notify
        Log.d("ConnectionSuspended", "Connection Suspended. Status: " + i);
        mgoogleMap.clear();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Notify
        Log.d("ConnectionFailed", "Connection Failed. Status: " + connectionResult.toString());
        mgoogleMap.clear();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}



@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Instantiating the inner class
    MapClassInner inner = new MapClassInner(map);

    //Trying to access the inner LatLng variable
    LatLng coords = inner.getLatLng();

    //Gives me a NullPointerException

    //Converting them to String values
    String lat = String.valueOf(coords.latitude);
    String lng = String.valueOf(coords.longitude);

    //Sending broadcast Intent
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(MyLocationReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(RESPONSE_LAT, lat);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(RESPONSE_LNG, lng);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
}
```

How can I get the `LatLng` from the inner class? I was thinking about EventBus for this. Will it work? And yes, please do go a little easy on me; I'm relatively new to Android & Java.

Comment: turn `private LatLng latLng;` to `LatLng latLng;`

Answer (score 1):

What I did to simplify this across all my code is create an 'AppData.java' class that is static, and accessible from any class in my package.  Then I put data like this in there.

```
public class AppData
{

    private static final AppData appData = new AppData();   // Make a static instance so it is not re-inited.

    // My data
    public Location lastKnownLocation;

    /**
     * Method to return the static instance of the AppData.
     *
     * @return An AppData object that is static so you can get/set global data across the application.
     */
     public static AppData getInstance() {return appData;}
}
```

You can add getters and setters.  I also gave mine a constructor that took a Context, and only called that once from my Main Activity, and it let me implement Preference Management from within the class, which was helpful for more complex data I keep there for persistence.

To use it anywhere, just do this:

```
AppData appData = AppData.getInstance();
appData.lastKnownLocation = <whatever your code does>
```

Etc...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll try it out, and mark your answer as accepted if it works. Thanks! :)